# innerHTML assignment removes all (including the last) whitespace in a empty tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I assign a string with html tags to a newly created div:

```js
const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
wrapper.innerHTML = this.html
```

`this.html` looks like this (please note the whitespace in the span.b tag):

```html
<span class="a"></span><span class="b" data-topicId="mark.001" data-type="R">
                    </span><span class="c"><span class="d">
```

After the innerHTML assignment I render the HTML with vue:

```js
return {
    name: 'NormalizedContent',
    template: wrapper.outerHTML,
    [...]
}
```

up until the last wrapper.outerHTML I can see multiple (at least one) whitespace with `console.log`, after it is rendered, the whitespace is gone.

[image: screenshot from the browser inspector]

I want to keep at least one and I can't replace them programmatically e.g. with `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Use `white-space: pre` to preserve white-space.

Comment: `.innerHTML` doesn't remove white space. However, default HTML display semantics collapse white space. Also, the browser debug console does not faithfully reproduce HTML, it instead formats it for convenience relative to the HTML spec.